# Is there a way that I can identify rows in SQL Server where a column contains just one word?

Tags: sql-server

I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Phrase] 
(
    [PhraseId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [English] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [FormId] INT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PhraseId] ASC) 
)
```

Is there a way I can change the `[FormId]` to be 1 if there is a single word in the `[English]` column and a 2 if not ?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define "a single word".  Check for the presence of a space character?  Something else?

Comment: Assuming that having more than a single word means that there is a space/blank character, you can set an UPDATE of the record with a CASE, something `CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(TRIM(English),' ',1) > 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END`.

Comment: @FDavidov - Could you add that as an answer with the syntax for the full update. If that looks okay to others I'd like to accept that.  Thanks

Comment: Can you show some example data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea would be:

```
UPDATE Phrase
   SET FormId = (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(TRIM(English),' ',1) > 0 THEN 2
                      ELSE                                         1
                 END
                ) ;
```

Note: I didn't verify this so make sure you test it before running the actual update.

Comment: `ISNULL(CHARINDEX(TRIM(English),' ',1), 1)` should it take NULL into account?

Comment: Good point. The OP should assess if this condition is possible (i.e. `English = NULL`).